# Python/Selenium javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, прокрутка, test-automation

У меня есть метод при использовании которого я получаю ошибку:

> javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function

вот собственно сам метод(если коротко, то его суть скролл до элемента)

```
def scroll_to_element(self, locator):
    return self.driver.execute_script("argument[0].scrollInToView();", locator)
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае проблема была в том, что локатор вел на список, нужно было указать конкретный элемент из списка